# How to get colored pdf text output with docbook via dblatex?

Tags: pdf-generation, docbook, dblatex

I need to output some hex-data with some bytes highlighted with colored background. Bytes in the data that represent red color values should have red background. That's why I chose

```
<emphasis role="red"></emphasis>
```

to be the tag of choice.

## HTML output

For HTML output I use

```
  <xsl:param name="emphasis.propagates.style" select="1"/>
```

in the xsl file and

```
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

in the stylesheet.
This works flawlessly.

## PDF output

For PDF output I use dblatex and tried (file fo.xsl)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:d="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/transitional"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="draft.mode">no</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="imagedata.default.scale">maxwidth=12cm</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="emphasis[@role='red']">
    <xsl:param name="content">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:text>{\color{red}</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$content"/>
    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And (file test.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.3//EN"
  "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.3/docbookx.dtd">
<article lang="en">
  <title>Test</title>
  <para>
    <screen>0240h: 00 20 <emphasis role="red">00</emphasis> 21</screen>
  </para>
</article>
```

With the following command to build latex source for checking:

```
dblatex --backend=pdftex --xslt=xsltproc \
    --input-format=xml --type=tex \
    --xsl-user=fo.xsl --verbose --output=test.tex test.xml
```

This does not work. Emphasised text is still italic, as shown in an excerpt from the resulting test.tex:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=1,escapeinside={<t>}{</t>},moredelim={**[is][\bfseries]{<b>}{</b>}},moredelim={**[is][\itshape]{<i>}{</i>}},]
0240h: 00 20 <i>00</i> 21\end{lstlisting}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mzjn stated, the screen tag was a problem. After reading the linked resource, the final template that works for me in this case, and produces output similar to the html look, is this:

```
<xsl:template match="emphasis[@role='red']" mode="latex.programlisting">
  <xsl:param name="co-tagin" select="'&lt;:'"/>
  <xsl:param name="rnode" select="/"/>
  <xsl:param name="probe" select="0"/>
  <xsl:param name="content">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:param>
  <xsl:text>&lt;t&gt;\colorbox{red}{</xsl:text>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$content"/>
  <xsl:text>}&lt;/t&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

which leads to the following latex output:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=1,escapeinside={<t>}{</t>},moredelim={**[is][\bfseries]{<b>}{</b>}},moredelim={**[is][\itshape]{<i>}{</i>}},]
0240h: 00 20 <t>\colorbox{red}{00}</t> 21\end{lstlisting}
```

Maybe it would be better to add another moredelim to lstlisting than using the escapeinside, but with this solution, this question is answered for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are using dblatex, which is a tool (a set of XSLT stylesheet modules) that produces PDF output from DocBook where the intermediate format is LaTeX rather than XSL-FO. So in order to customize the look and feel of inline text (such as `emphasis`), you have to use LaTeX. The following template should work for you:

```
<xsl:template match="emphasis[@role='red']">
  <xsl:param name="content">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:param>
  <xsl:text>{\color{red}</xsl:text>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$content"/>
  <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that it says `emphasis` (without a `d:` prefix). dblatex strips out the namespace from DocBook 5 source documents at the start of the transformation, so there should be no namespaces in customizations either.

---

The fact that the `emphasis` occurs within `screen` (which is a "verbatim" element; see http://dblatex.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/sec-verbatim.html) makes things more complicated. My customization suggestion does work if the `screen` start and end tags are removed from your sample `para`.

If **`bold`** text instead of red-coloured is an acceptable compromise, you can use the following in your XML document:

```
<screen>0240h: 00 20 <emphasis role="bold">00</emphasis> 21</screen>
```

No customization is needed for this to work. `role="bold"` is handled by the default dblatex stylesheets.

Comment: Removing the apply-imports doesn't change the output in any way. I don't care much about if it's still italic or not, the color is essential.

Comment: @user2011659: OK, sorry, I misunderstood. I'll try to get back with a better answer.

Comment: The actual solution does not work either. I edited the post to reflect the current state and added more info.